# Jquery Selected Class

Tags: jquery

I have two level dropdown list: Home Categories Contact, etc.

Under the "Categories" there are sub categories.

I want to apply selected class to "Categories" whenever the user selects something from sub categories.

For example when user clicks "home" home is given class of selected but when user selects anything from subcategories under the "Categories" it should be given class of "selected". At present my jquery code is:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        $('a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');  
    });
});
```

Which is adding selected class to dropdown items also.

Please help me out

Comment: Show us your lists markups..

Comment: You need to provide more code than this, like your html and ideally a demo with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use unique ids and same class names to all the subcategories.If any of it is clicked you can add the classess you require.

something like this

```
$(function() {
$('.subcategory').click(function() {
    $('.category').addClass('selected');


});
```

Comment: But what about "Home" link it will not be given selected class if i use your code

Comment: Keep the code as it is u did but add a if clause for subcategory clicks and then add the above code to it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking for the `.parent()` jQuery method. Simply give the subcategories a class of subcategories and when one of them are clicked, set the style on the `$(this).parent()`

```
$(function() {


    $('.cat').click(function() {

        $('.cat').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');           

    });

    $('.subcat').click(function() {

        $('.cat').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).parent().addClass('selected');           

    });

});
```

Comment: But what about "Home" link it will not be given selected class if i use your code